# ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Privacy on flutter

Tags: flutter, app-store, privacy-policy, ios-privacy-settings

I have my code on flutter on vscode and i use xcode just to compile my ios versión, i added the new PrivacyInfo in the folder /ios after of that i tried to compile and upload it to the appstore, but the warnings still appear, i don´t known if i need to configure something else on xcode in order that the app can read the PrivacyInfo file. if somebody can help me i will be gratefull .

i added the new PrivacyInfo in the folder /ios after of that i tried to compile and upload it to the appstore, but the warnings still appear.

Comment: Make sure you have selected Target Membership for your PrivacyInfo file.